# Where is the best place to introduce your own Pen&Paper System?

Tags: publishing

I am working on a tabletop RPG (SteamDICE) that uses lots of online integration (web-based and mobile devices), but to kick start the project to the next stage, we need supporters, backers and feedback. Even a great project is worthless, if nobody knows it.

**What are good strategies to promote a new game?**

Comment: @BESW To be fair I think that was the product of enthusiasm rather than shoehorning, but yes, regardless of reason it wasn't material to the question. :)

Comment: Comments are not for chatting in.

Answer (score 6):

There's a few options that you can use in tandem.

**Blog**

Blog is easy, goes right with your core website.  The tricky part to the blog is if it is not something you are already doing, do not try to do it "just to do it" - update once month at least, but don't spam out updates just to fill content.  Meaningful content is more useful than just updating all the time.

**Online Communities**

Forums, large blogs, etc.  If you are already part of appropriate gaming (or related - say, fantasy, or sci-fi, or whatever) communities, it's pretty easy to find a promotions or "other" folder and put up an announcement and link your game in your tagline.

If you are not, then you should participate in a real way - that is, don't show up, drop promotion and leave.  Go to sites you'd actually like to drop in on, at least once a month and participate in MORE than promoting your game.

rpg.net is a pretty good site in this regard - they have an ongoing thread series for crowdfunding and kickstarters, so that's a nice extra.

**Podcasts**

If there's any gaming podcasts you're into, see if you can get a shoutout or guest star on them.  Maybe give them a free copy of the game, etc.

**Demo Play Video**

Short 3-10 minute videos of some demos of key points of play - how the rules work, neat bits, and share them.

Answer (score 5):

One of the best way is to start a blog and develop an audience. The downside is that it is a slow way to start. However if you are successful in attracting readers then the odds of finding an initial market with your RPG is much higher. This the process that allowed me to have a small amount of success selling products with my Bat in the Attic Games.

Answer (score 0):

As an independent developer your lucky to be in a very indie friendly time. I'd say the first few places you should check out are the communities of your peers. Places like "The Forge" and Indie Press Revolution are full of people who have done exactly what you are doing and succeeded, some very well.  Many are more than willing to share thier experiences and lessons learned.

The forge - http://www.indie-rpgs.com/forge/index.php

IPR -  http://www.indiepressrevolution.com/xcart/

Comment: The Forge ended; all that's left are archives.

Comment: IPR is a store. You won't find anyone to ask about promotion and feedback there. It's great, but it's only useful *after* you're at the point where you're looking for someone to sell and distribute your finished game.