# Best way to promote the Indie RPG I am developing

Tags: publishing

I am currently developing a Indie RPG that I hope to Kickstart next year. What is the best way to promote it? (I know this is a common question)

Currently I have found Google+ communities the best, and I'm using [a Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/FraggedEmpire) to upload snippets of my work. I am directing people to email me if they are interested in beta testing.

Is there anything I am missing? What is it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Marketing and Promotion.

Comment: This question is *on topic* because an RPG expert could give a [better/different/more specific answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about how to get the word out on an RPG than someone with different expertise.

Comment: In fact, it's so on-topic that [we've already answered](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4632/how-do-i-let-the-world-know-about-my-role-playing-system) this question not once, [but twice](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26968/where-is-the-best-place-to-introduce-your-own-penpaper-system). Wade, the answers on those two question should help, I'd think?

Comment: I agree that this is both on topic and a duplicate (unless it is expanded on greatly such that there would be a more specific answer based on its niche).