# How can I advertise a game with a homebrew system?

Tags: homebrew

As a long time gamemaster I have reached a point where I want to create my own system and run players through it but I have noticed that people tend to shy away from systems that are homemade. For example if I decide to run WoD or D&D 5e I'll have 10 recruits minimum ready to play but if I say 'I made a system similar to WoD' then maybe 1 person who will be extremely hesitant.

So what I want to ask is that how can I advertise a homebrew game I made in a way that does not make people shy from it as soon as they hear the word 'homebrew'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I let the world know about my role-playing system?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4632/how-do-i-let-the-world-know-about-my-role-playing-system) or [Where is the best place to introduce your own Pen&Paper System?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/26968/14878)

Comment: Are you asking about [play-by-post] and [online-roleplaying]? If yes, you might want to add those tags, as answers will be different than if you're interested in starting an (appropriately socially-distanced) in-person game at your FLGS.

Comment: @ObliviousSage add it to the question. Tags are just to describe questions, not to provide info or constrain answers.

Comment: I think this isn't a dupe because the other question is about marketing the system to a broader audience as something that audience might run, whereas this is about getting people to agree to play a game you are running with a system you've made.